# MacBook Air M1's trackpad becomes unresponsive after closing lid

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I bought a new MacBook Air M1 last summer, and it's not given me a problem until today. I was confused at first, but after exploring for a bit the problem is easy enough to reproduce. Here's what I know:

1. When I boot up the laptop, everything works fine.
2. As soon as I close the lid and open it back, the trackpad and keyboard become completely unresponsive (except for the TouchID key, which allows me to turn off the Mac).
3. I've reset the SMC following Apple's intructions. Doesn't do anything.
4. I've completely erased my hard drive and reinstalled macOS Monterey, since I thought it might be a Ventura bug. The problem persists.
5. The computer itself is responsive: I can let a YouTube video playing when closing and it will continue playing after opening the lid. I have also tried sending some picture from my iPhone using AirDrop and it works normally. It just is not responsive.
6. The problem goes away after booting the computer.

I just cannot work like this. Is there any known solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would take it back to the shop. If a 'brand new' OS volume exhibits the problem (and other Macs do not report this), then it's not the software.

Comment: I just called to an official Apple retailer, I'll be taking the computer there next Monday. I guess it must be hardware related, since I wiped everything on the HD and it kept happening.

Comment: What was the outcome? They fixed it for you?